# How to optimize Thymeleaf utility calls from html?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have a thymeleaf `html` page that shows all rows from a database `@Entity`.

Problem: the entity has a complex field that is mapped with a hibernate `AttributeConverter`. When I want to show the field as `String` in html, I have to call that converter to onvert the complex field to a string representation, like:

```
<td th:text="${{T(org.exmaple.domain.utils.AddressConverter).convertToString(row?.address)}}" />
```

With source:

```
//assume I have the address only in this format
public class AddressConverter<Address, String> {
    public String convertToString(Address address) {
        if (address == null) return null;
        return address.getZip() + " " + address.getTown();
    }
}
```

Question: how can I optimize those utility imports in thymeleaf?
I'm looking for something simple like:

```
<td th:text="${{addressUtil.convertToString(row?.address)}}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's go backward, starting from your requirements. The following is something you would like to have in your Thymeleaf template ...

```
<td th:text="${addressConverter.convertToString(row?.address)}" />
```

To call `addressConverter` 's function `convertToString` like this, you would need to have the object available in your model. Basically in your controller have a static variable ...

```
private static final AddressConverter addressConverter = new AddressConverter();
```

And after add it to the model ...

```
model.addAttribute("addressConverter", addressConverter);
```

Comment: Is this the only chance? I mean, isn't it possible to somehow automatically "expose" the `addresseConverter` as a variable, instead of having it explicit to the `model`? Because my `@Controller` has mutiple mapping methods like `@GetMapping` , `@PostMapping`, `@PutMapping`. And then I'd have to add the address converter to the model in each method, repeatedly. I don't feel that's how things should work...

Comment: Now you asking a different question. There are methods to add an attribute in the controller once with `@ModelAttribute` and `@ControllerAdvice` [annotations](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-and-the-modelattribute-annotation). While return to your original question, the described method is not the "only" chance, indeed, but it's simple and serve your needs. Another method may be to extend Spring `Formatter` like in this [example](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#configuring-a-conversion-service). You can create custom formatted for your `Address` object.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that spring beans can simply be accessed with the `@` parameter, like:

```
<div th:text="${@addressConverter.convertToString()}">...</div>
```

Of course this assumes it's not a static utility.

If anybody knows how to better expose a static utility to thymeleaf, please answer.